# Cómo identificar en que rango se encuentra un número en Android?

Tags: java, android

Necesito identificar dentro de que grupo de números se encuentra una variable.

Por ejemplo tengo los siguientes grupos:

```
[00, 10, "Grupo 1"],
[11, 20, "Grupo 2"],
[21, 30, "Grupo 3"]
```

Por ejemplo si tengo una variable con el número 13 que me imprima en un toast grupo 2.

Actualmente lo hago con un **else if** pero el verdadero problema es que son aproximadamente 50 grupos y quiero ver alguna forma más optima de realizarlo.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Hola Gustavo, agrega de que forma lo has tratado de realizar.

Comment: Por lo que veo de tus grupos todos estan en escala de 10 en 10, lo que puedes hacer es dividir el numero que interesa entre 10 y de alli identificas el grupo. Ejm: 13/10 = 1.3, solo tomas el entero = 1 por lo tanto es del grupo 1....concatenas las respuestas

Comment: En realidad lo hice de 10 en 10 solo para ejemplificarlo, la escala no tiene un valor en específico.